# Creating objects from YAML, already initialized constant

Tags: ruby, initialization, constants, iteration

Two problems, that probably are related:

I'm retreiving a number of 'persons' from a YAML-file to an array, and now i'm trying to create classes from that array.

These objects are then to placed in a new array.

It actually works out fine, if you dont consider the fact that the object added last replaces *all* the previously added.

In my case i get five identical copies of object #5, where i rather like to see five different ones.

My guess is that the error results somewhere in my iterator to get all the 'persons' from the YAML.

I'm getting a cuople of warnings, regarding the 're-use' of constants:
NEWSTR and NEWAL.

```
getPost = 0
loopa = 0

     while loopa < personsInYAML
        NEWSTR = TEST.fetch(getPost)
        NEWAL = NEWSTR.split(' ')
        getPost+=1

        puts "*****************************************"
        nyloop = loopa+1
        puts "PERSON: " + nyloop.to_s + " name: " + NEWAL.fetch(1)

        nameToArray = Person.new
        outputArray.insert(loopa, nameToArray)
        loopa+=1
    end
```

Persons-class

```
class Person

    def initialize
        @name
        @age
        @length
        @weight
        @misc
    end


    def name
        name = NEWAL.fetch(1)
        return name
    end

    if NEWAL.include?("age:")

        def age
            x = NEWAL.index("age:")+1   
            age =  NEWAL.fetch(x)
            return age
        end
    end

    if NEWAL.include?("length:")
        def length
            x = NEWAL.index("length:")+1
            length = NEWAL.fetch(x)
            return length
        end
    end

    if NEWAL.include?("weight:")
        def weight
            x = NEWAL.index("weight:")+1
            weight = NEWAL.fetch(x)
            return weight
        end
    end

    if NEWAL.include?("misc:")
        def misc
            x = NEWAL.index("misc:")+1
            misc = NEWAL.fetch(x)
            return misc
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking the wrong approach to populating your Person class.  The only thing your loop is doing is to create brand new Person classes and stick them in an array.  It isn't actually initializing the person class at all.

It looks like what you are trying to do is to use a constant (which you don't hold constant) to pass information to the Person class.  However, the code that you have in your Person class that is outside of the methods is only going to be run once - when the class loads for the first time, NOT at the time that you make a new Person.

You'd be better off changing your initialize method to take some arguments, and to create the class with appropriate arguments within the loop.

```
def initialize(name, age = nil, length = nil, weight = nil, misc = nil)
  # assign instance variables here
  @name = name
  ...
end
```

You appear to be trying to create dynamic accessors to the instance variables.  This doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  Just define accessors on all of them, and handle the case where the instance variables are nil in whatever code is calling the Person class.